# How can I split by the last point of a String?

Tags: java, string, split

I know I can split strings like this

```
String myString = "foo.bar";    
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(myString.split("."));
```

But my String looks like `20151221.1051.Test.01.properties`, it can have any number of dots, and I want to remove the `.properties` at the end (only by the last dot).

Comment: I wonder if there is a solution for example with regex. i know i can split by each point and "rebuild" the string without the last part.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `myString.lastIndexOf(".")` to get the index of the last dot.

For example, if you are sure that your input String contains at least one dot :

```
String name = myString.substring(0,myString.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `split`, you need to escape the dot (split expects a regular expression).

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(myString.split("\\."));
```

If you only need to remove the last part, you can use `replaceAll` and a regex:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("\\.[^.]*$", "");
```

Explanation:

- `\\.` looks for a dot
- `[^.]*` looks for 0 or more non dot characters
- `$` is the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

You could solve that using substring method like this:

```
string test = "20151221.1051.Test.01.properties"
test = test.Substring(0, test.LastIndexOf('.'))
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there with your code :) a small change would fetch you what you need :)

Here's what you can do:

```
String myString = "201512211051.Test.01.properties";    
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(myString.split("."));
strings.set(strings.size() - 1,"");
```

now you have replaced the last part of split array :) join the list to create string. Use whichever way pleases you :) either loop through elements or use String.join provided in ios 8 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
 String myString = "20151221.1051.Test.01.properties";    
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(myString.substring(0,myString.lastIndexOf(".")).split("\\.(?=[^\\.])"));
    for (String string : strings) {
        System.out.println(string);

    }
```

With `myString.substring(0,myString.lastIndexOf("."))` the file extension and with split `split("\\.(?=[^\\.])")` you have output:

```
  20151221
  1051
  Test
  01
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your question is more about getting the File Name minus extension. There are enough open source libraries out there that can help you get this done. For example: Apache Commons IO:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

There is a method called getBaseName() that helps you get the name of the file minus full path and minus the extension. Another method called getExtension() will only get you the extension of the file. Slice and dice all you want!